# xamdatagrid binding a list to a listview inside a cell

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

```
List<string> UsedBy = new List<string>();
```

here is the XamDataGrid code

```
<igDP:Field Name="UsedBy">
  <igDP:Field.Settings>
    <igDP:FieldSettings >
      <igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
         <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">       
            <ToggleButton x:Name="UsedByList"  Content="Select Calibration tools" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
           </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
        </Style>
       </igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
      </igDP:FieldSettings>
     </igDP:Field.Settings>
   </igDP:Field>
```

i want to be able to display a toggle button inside my xamdatagridCell.
however when i use my code the DataGrid doesn't display this column.

If i change the type of UsedBy to any other type, for example int. the list DataGrid will display the UsedBy column.

I don't understand why XamDataGrid doesn't recognize List<>.

Comment: requirement is not clear..

Comment: @Sankarann is it more clear after i edited?

Comment: How does the `UsedBy` is mapped with the `Field`?

Comment: i have a grid with UsedBy as a property of the collection bounded to the grid. like any other XamDataGrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
just replace the field with UnboundField

<igDP:UnboundField Name="UsedBy">
      <igDP:UnboundFField.Settings>
        <igDP:FieldSettings >
          <igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
             <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">       
                <ToggleButton x:Name="UsedByList"  Content="Select Calibration tools" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
               </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
            </Style>
           </igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
          </igDP:FieldSettings>
         </igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
       </igDP:UnboundField>
```